# Bitcoin api - how to create wallet

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I was looking at [bitcoin api](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Api), but I haven't find any way to create wallet and account. I'd like to create them on local server with just rpc calls. Are there any way to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the blockchain.info API, very useful. All address will be belong to you and more easy than RPC.

Answer (score 3):

You create the wallet (wallet.dat) automatically when you start the bitcoind deamon.

Accounts in the wallet can be created with API call `getnewaddress <account>`